# A Perl one-liner into a bash function?

Tags: bash, perl, function, alias

Is there a way to make a perl one-liner into a bash function?

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/.bashrc:
stopwatch() {
   perl -wE 'for (reverse 1..(shift)-1) {system q!clear!;open FIGLET,q!|figlet -f banner -c!;printf FIGLET "%2d:%02d",$_/60,$_%60;sleep 1}' "$1"
}
```

`source`-ing `~/.bashrc` complains as follows:

- unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
- syntax error near unexpected token `reverse'
- and so on..

Usual [shell wrapping](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html#EX56) works of course, but here I try to have a bash alias/function invoking [perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=46168).

There must be a way without needing to create a brand new `*.pl` file. Much appreciated!

Comment: Why is it such a problem to have a script to run?

Comment: I thought once you can do a one-liner, it would be nice to turn it into the .bashrc as well. Otherwise I'm forced to maintain a new directory/scripts/$PATH/alias... I just feel better when things stay simple :)

Comment: Your definition of "simple" is quite complicated.

Comment: So basically this command is given like `stopwatch 360` (360 seconds), which then prints some sort of ascii graphic representation of a stopwatch counting down (hence reverse), showing minutes and seconds. Feels like this could be written easily in bash.

Comment: So a one-liner used more than twice should be better a script?

Comment: `q!..!` as a quoting is good only if you want to torture someone.

Comment: @Сухой27 Personally, I think `q; ... ;` is the optimal torture instrument. `$??s;:;;:s;$?;;;` (that actually means something :))

Comment: @TLP indeed, but I let it immediately to `Deparse` which doesn't feel the pain.

Comment: @Сухой27 I did it for the matter of stressing out "hey, an external call here!" :) Usually, I do not do this in a proper script..

Comment: Since you perform `open` once each iteration (each second), you do not need it at all and should just use backticks instead, e.g. `qx(clear; figlet ...)` (using `qx()` since stackoverflow formatting uses backticks)

Comment: You might get around some of the quoting problems by using something like this: `perl -e'$x = shift; while ($x-- >= 0) { $m = int $x/60; $s = $x % 60; qx(clear; figlet -f banner -c $m:$s) }'`

Comment: and you're using `set -vx` inside your function to debug how the shell is interpreting that definition? Good luck.

Comment: @TLP okay, I'll use `qx` then :) It was I read in Learning Perl that using backticks and not storing output is a waste.. But I don't dispute it has to be that always.. :)

Comment: @TLP that while loop is definitively neater, though I really have to resort to a dedicated script..

Comment: @paveljurca Ah yes, I forgot. You are using `system` and `open` which prints to your console, whereas `qx()` captures output. You should either `print qx( ...)` or use system `system(" ... ")`. The benefit of using `print` is that you get output to stdout, so it can be captured and manipulated.

Comment: @TLP Thank you for the clarification! So I guess now `qx(...)` should be faster than the `system` and `open` with an extra pipe...

Comment: @paveljurca If you want to know the speed, use [`Benchmark`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark). The difference might be noticeable when doing updates every second, but normally I don't think it would matter much.

Comment: It seems to me you don't need the Perl here.

Comment: @briandfoy Right, it's not as this particular case as it's rather a wondering whether the bash lets you do that (which apparently does not for I don't see a valid reason when `perl -e '...'` is the same like invoking `find` or `mplayer`)

So it fails on that escaping..

Comment: I don't think it does make much sense the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30914955/revisions) you just added. Start a bounty to get more attention, reword in a more clear way, because you never know when a [good] solution can appear. Rolling back it.

Comment: @fedorqui I know but given I don't have even that 50 rep for a bounty... And it also might be there's simply no solution to this question hence many already pointed out its apparent inutility :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to run bash and perl script together in this way as well.
Moreover in your case -E is where I doubt. perl -e always works but perl -E didn't work in perl 5.8.8

See the code of combining perl with bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash_test
echo "bash commands that you wish to write"
exit 0
# End of Bash part of the script.
# =======================================================
#!/usr/bin/perl
# This part of the script must be invoked with -x option.
print "here you can use your simple system() or exec() that you might wish to use right?";
# End of Perl part of the script.
```

Comment: :D Right. This is just to show as an example as whatever you are asking we hardly do such things ;)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to export a perl one-liner as a bash function/alias; I was just curious whether it would be possible.. And as @Sobrique already pointed out: it's not that much meaningful... I'm aware of it..  But anyway, thanks ;)